# Is it possible sending websocket messages to a kafka topic?

Tags: websocket, apache-kafka

I am trying to find a way to consume messages that being sent by a websocket to a kafka topic (the messages are sent by the websocket to the address 'ws://address:port/topic_name' and I want to add all of those messages to a kafka topic).
I read about kafka connect and tried to find a way to do it with it but it doesnt seem to work...
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Kafka Connector to a socket in Confluent Platform.

I work in a team that use Kafka in production and our source is a socket, so your options are to use platforms that support this socket->Kafka producing, or write one by yourself.

About possible platforms, I think most of them will be overkill though you can utilize them for this problem, some options are:
 1. [NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/) or [MiniFi](https://nifi.apache.org/minifi/index.html) for smaller loads, use [PublishKafka Processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-0-9-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafka/)
 2. [StreamSets](https://streamsets.com/) with [Kafka Producer Destination](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Destinations/KProducer.html)
 3. [Apache Flume](https://flume.apache.org/)- not very recommended, this project is stops to evolve.

If you wish to write your own producer, you basically have to create a listener on this port, and produce the incoming messages to Kafka; if this is a web socket, just get the payload of the requests and produce them to Kafka.
Example Kafka Producer Code can be copied from [tutorialspoint simple producer example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_simple_producer_example.htm)*

Here are some open-source projects examples:
1. https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-socket-source
2. https://github.com/kafka-socket/miniature_engine
3. https://github.com/dhanuka84/kafka-connect-tcp
4. https://github.com/krux/tcp-stream-kafka-producer

Comment: "There is no Kafka connector for sockets" ... "here are some links to projects which use socket sources"... Which is it?

Comment: By saying "Kafka connector" I meant Kafka Connect framework by Confluent.  Edited the answer to Kafka Connect instead of connector

Comment: Kafka Connect is Apache Licensed, not only in Confluent Platform. They write connectors (plugins).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Kafka connect is that you have some sort of external integration that serves as storage. This can be SAP, Salesforce, RDBMS, MQ or anything else that has state. You websocket endpoint does not have data, you can not poll it it is someone else that is invoking it and there fore the data is transfered. Now if you know who is actualy holding the data than you can potentialy build a conector using this guide. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html

For your particular case, the best you can do is either to use Kafka Producer API https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/producer.html
and from your websocket enpoint use this producer to post a message to the topic, or even better if you are using spring you can use a higher level abstraction, that will be KafkaTemplate https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#sending-messages.

Comment: @cricket_007 by state i meant data.

Comment: That's also not true. There are source connectors that generate random data and have no state/data

Comment: @cricket_007 Are you saying that your RAM is not a data storage ? :) The fact it is hidden by your operating system and language does not make it less of a storage :) Don't play it too smart, the connector - the name states well enough its purpose.

Comment: @cricket_007 plus if you decide to generate random data within your connector, you will mess up with the single responsibility principle IMO. In order to not break it you would have some sort of external mechanism to create the test data and then you would connect to it through your connector. But again the storage and what you are connecting to is your generator which can be in memory in which case the RAM is your storage.

Comment: Feel free to make an issue on this if you think it isn't useful https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/voluble#voluble & https://www.confluent.io/blog/easy-ways-generate-test-data-kafka/

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I work for MigratoryData.

You can check out [MigratoryData's solution for Kafka](https://migratorydata.com/solutions/kafka/). MigratoryData is a scalable WebSocket server. The MigratoryData Source/Sink Connector for Kafka makes use of Kafka Connect API and can be used to stream data in real-time from Kafka to WebSocket clients and vice versa. The main advantage of the solution is it extends Kafka messaging to WebSocket clients while preserving Kafka's key features like guaranteed delivery, message ordering, etc.

Comment: @Mihai When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. 
Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.